# Using Node's makeSafe on Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js's `primordials.js` file (the one I based this question's code off of is [found here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodejs/node/54e022315d7e037c429afbda73cf8bb8ff96d667/lib/internal/per_context/primordials.js)) there is a function `makeSafe` which is passed a builtin constructor and produces a class derived from it which is protected against monkeypatching. `SafeSet` is based on `Set`, `SafeMap` is based on `Map`, and so forth.

`makeSafe` is insufficient when the class in question has methods which return iterators whose prototypes are anonymous. For this, the `createSafeIterator` is used to create a frozen class that produces iterator objects that use the original prototypes' `next` functions.

The original `primordials.js` doesn't have a `SafeArray`, so I chose to make one with it. The trouble is that `SafeArray`'s returned iterators throw an error claiming the inner `next` is not a function even though `typeof` reports that it is.

Here is the code:

```
// Derived from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodejs/node/54e022315d7e037c429afbda73cf8bb8ff96d667/lib/internal/per_context/primordials.js

"use strict";

const { apply, bind, call } = Function.prototype;
const uncurryThis = bind.bind(call);

const applyBind = bind.bind(apply);

const createSafeIterator = (factory, next) => {
  class SafeIterator {
    constructor(iterable) {
      this._iterator = factory(iterable);
    }
    next() {
      console.log("SafeIterator#next: Inner next's type is " + typeof next);
      return next(this._iterator);
    }
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
      return this;
    }
  }
  Object.setPrototypeOf(SafeIterator.prototype, null);
  Object.freeze(SafeIterator.prototype);
  Object.freeze(SafeIterator);
  return SafeIterator;
};

const copyProps = (src, dest) => {
  Reflect.ownKeys(src).forEach((key) => {
    if (!Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(dest, key)) {
      Reflect.defineProperty(
        dest,
        key,
        Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(src, key));
    }
  });
};

const makeSafe = (unsafe, safe) => {
  if (Symbol.iterator in unsafe.prototype) {
    const dummy = new unsafe();
    let next;

    Reflect.ownKeys(unsafe.prototype).forEach((key) => {
      if (!Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(safe.prototype, key)) {
        const desc = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(unsafe.prototype, key);
        if (
          typeof desc.value === 'function' &&
          desc.value.length === 0 &&
          // Original: Symbol.iterator in (desc.value.call(dummy) ?? {})
          Symbol.iterator in (typeof desc.value.call(dummy) === "object" ? desc.value.call(dummy) : {}) // Rewritten to handle non-object results such as from Array#join
        ) {
          const createIterator = uncurryThis(desc.value);
          next ??= uncurryThis(createIterator(dummy).next);
          const SafeIterator = createSafeIterator(createIterator, next);
          desc.value = function() {
            return new SafeIterator(this);
          };
        }
        Reflect.defineProperty(safe.prototype, key, desc);
      }
    });
  } else {
    copyProps(unsafe.prototype, safe.prototype);
  }
  copyProps(unsafe, safe);

  Object.setPrototypeOf(safe.prototype, null);
  Object.freeze(safe.prototype);
  Object.freeze(safe);
  return safe;
};

var SafeArray = makeSafe(Array, class SafeArray extends Array {
  constructor (i) {
    super(i);
  }
});

var SafeSet = makeSafe(Set, class SafeSet extends Set {
  constructor (i) {
    super(i);
  }
});

var sa = new SafeArray(1, 2, 3);
var ss = new SafeSet([1, 2, 3]);

console.log([...ss]); // Prints the typeof report three times and then "[1, 2, 3]" (without quotes and separated with newlines)
console.log([...sa]); // Prints typeof report and then throws "TypeError: next is not a function"
```

Why does it say that the inner `next` function is not function in the case of `SafeArray`?

Comment: This: `typeof desc.value.call(dummy) === "object"` is a dangerous test in this context. If the Array method call returns an Array this test will pass. If you expect this to fail, you'll need to call `desc.value.call(dummy).constructor === "object"`. The `typeof` code works for a Set because the methods in a Set Object manipulate objects while the methods in an Array may return an Array (who's type is Object).

Comment: Another observation: `const dummy = new unsafe();` requires that the constructor can be called with no arguments.  That is not true of all constructors.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Okay, but how does that explain the screwy behavior regarding `next`? And under what circumstances would `desc.value.call(dummy).constructor === "object"` ever evaluate to `true`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Then the Node.js developers restrict its use to certain constructors.

Comment: @Melab - please see my answer - was too complicated to simply say it here.

Answer (score 0):

### **There are two problems**

**1.** The first problem occurs when reflecting each method in the Array prototype in order to test their returned structure.

The Array prototype methods have many more variations of return types than you have accounted for in your complex `if()` statement. For instance, [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) returns `undefined` while [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#return_value) may return any number of datatypes that are valid as an Array element.

**2.** The second problem relates to using the `typeof` operator in an attempt to determine if the return type from the called method of the Array prototype. This test indicates that you want to operate on only those Array prototype methods that return a data type that has a `Symbol.iterator`.

The problem: `typeof` returns "object" for Array objects and is a naive test in this code.

To demonstrate, the following code snippet reduces your code to a Minimal Reproducible example. I have extracted the complex test into a separate function to demonstrate the issues above. The errors are caught and logged for your reference.

It is important to recognize that not a single Array prototype method was processed using your tests.

```js
let unsafe = Array;
let safe = {};
safe.prototype = {};
if (Symbol.iterator in unsafe.prototype) {
  const dummy = new unsafe();
  let next;

  Reflect.ownKeys(unsafe.prototype).forEach((key) => {
    if (!Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(safe.prototype, key)) {
      const desc = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(unsafe.prototype, key);
      console.log(`Testing ${desc.value.name}`)
      if (complexTest(desc.value, dummy))
      {
        console.log(`Processing ${desc.value.name}`);
        console.log(' ');
      } else {
        console.log(`Not processed`);
        console.log(' ');
      }
    }
  });
}
function complexTest(toTest, dummy){
  if(!typeof toTest === 'function') return false;
  if(toTest.length !== 0) return false;
  let type;
  try {
    type = typeof toTest.call(dummy);
    Symbol.iterator in typeof toTest.call(dummy);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error with ${type} ||`, err.message);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log('done');
```

### **Solution**

The simple fix, as discussed in the comments to your question is to change replace the use of `typeof` with the use of the `constructor` property. This simple change will ensure that you only check for `Symbol.iterator` on the return from those methods that actually return an Array object.

Here is the same code as above with that single change. Please note the remarkable difference in the results:

```js
let unsafe = Array;
let safe = {};
safe.prototype = {};
if (Symbol.iterator in unsafe.prototype) {
  const dummy = new unsafe();
  let next;

  Reflect.ownKeys(unsafe.prototype).forEach((key) => {
    if (!Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(safe.prototype, key)) {
      const desc = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(unsafe.prototype, key);
      console.log(`Testing ${desc.value.name}`)
      if (complexTest(desc.value, dummy))
      {
        console.log(`Processing ${desc.value.name}`);
        console.log(' ');
      } else {
        console.log(`Not processed`);
        console.log(' ');
      }
    }
  });
}
function complexTest(toTest, dummy){
  if(!typeof toTest === 'function') return false;
  if(toTest.length !== 0) return false;
  let type;
  try {
   type = typeof toTest.call(dummy);
    Symbol.iterator in toTest.call(dummy).constructor;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error with ${type} ||`, err.message);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log('done');
```

You may have to adjust your tests to cover more "unsafe" methods. I'll leave that to you.